# .htaccess mask /folder/subfolder to /folder/ contents but keeping url same

Tags: .htaccess, url, directory, mask, subdirectory

Hoping someone can figure this one out. I've tried looking but all the results i find seem to be similar but the other way around.

This is to be done via a htaccess file as thats all i have access too on my server for such things.

I have this url: mydomain.com/folder/subfolder/
Now i want anyone who goes to that url to see the contents of: mydomain.com/folder/
But always remain in within the url: /folder/subfolder/
So it just puts an extra folder in the url.
Is this even at all possible?

Comment: Is `subfolder` a real folder inside `/folder/`?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't have to be. i have nothing in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `/folder/.htaccess` have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/

RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ $1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: thought this was working, but i noticed it almost does.
The problem with the above is, when viewing mydomain.com/folder/  is puts the subfolder in. If the viewer goes to just the /folder/ i want the url to stay like that. but if the viewer goes to the url as /folder/subfolder/ i would like the url to then stay like that. hope that makes sense. and thanks for you help so far, it great.

Comment: Its not clear what you meant by **The problem with the above is, when viewing mydomain.com/folder/ is puts the subfolder in.** I have updated the answer based on my understanding. Test it in a new browser.